# In jquery how do I refer to a div with a certain title attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

In jquery how do I refer to a div with a certain title attribute?

```
$('#inner').attr("title:contains('" + position +"')").css('position', 'absolute');
```

this isnt working for me, If contains doesnt work in there how do I refer to a div with the title="div1" and change its css .  Thanks again!

EDIT:
I have multiple #inner divs, how can I go about referring to a specific one, if title will not work?  There must be some way to give these #inner divs some sort of identification so I can call them individually.

Comment: I think you're looking for a `<div title="div1">` element that is an ancestor of `#inner`. But something in my gut tells me that you actually have several `#inner` elements and you want the one that has a particular `title`. Please tell me that's not true!  :o)

Comment: @patrick exactly what I have haha.  I have multiple divs all with the ID=#inner I want to select a specific one and bring it to the front, thus the position:absolute css modify.  How else can I name these divs so I can have them by some sort of id, so I can call them individually?

Comment: anthonypliu - If you are going to reuse the same name, it can not be an `ID` attribute. You should use a `class` instead. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: anthonypliu - Is there a reason why you wouldn't be able to use classes instead of IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename your divs so they have a unique id and use class="inner" then use .each to cycle though them
or use similar code as above
$('.inner').find('div[title=div1]').css('position','absolute');
jquery doesnt like it when you dont play by the rules (multiple element with the same "unique" id

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a `div` that is an ancestor of `#inner` and has the title `div1`, do this:

```
$('#inner').find('div[title=div1]').css('position','absolute');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/find/
- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

---

**EDIT:**

Something tells me that you my have more than one `<div id='inner'>` and you're trying to get the one with a particular title.

If that is the case, your markup is invalid. You can not have more than one element on a page with the same ID.

You'll have to rethink your strategy if that's the case.

---

Here's an example of using a `class` attribute instead of ID, and selecting based on the `title` attribute:

HTML

```
<div class='inner' title='div1'>some content</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.inner[title=div1]').css('position','absolute');
```

This will select the element with the class `inner` that has the title `div1`. It uses the "attribute equals" selector.

There are many other types of selectors in jQuery that you can use. Here's a reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors

Comment: why use find? structuring the selector to read `'#inner div[title=div1]'` should work just as well. Pros/cons of my way?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `.attr('title')` to get the value of the title attribute.

`.attr` isn't for selecting elements, you can't pass the `:contains` selector to it.

Answer (score 0):

To select those with title attributes:

```
$("#inner > *[title!=]").css('position','absolute');
```

Comment: I would use `#inner [title]` since your example will only select direct descendents, the asterisk is not necessary, and neither is the '!='